# update float price mysql with python using variable

Tags: python, mysql

i'm trying to update my database mysql using python but it not work

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="myhost",
user="myuser",
password="mypass",
database="mydb"
)

prezzo = 385

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "Update calendario set costo_volo = \"prezzo\" where id_data = '753'"
mycursor.execute(sql)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "Prezzo Aggiornato! (prezzo €)")
```

If i use the number in the query it work, like this

```
sql = "Update calendario set costo_volo = 385 where id_data = '753'"
```

How i can use the variable?

Comment: Variables aren't replaced inside strings. You're trying to set it to the literal string `prezzo`, not the value of the variable. Use a prepared statement with parameter.

Comment: how i can make it?

Comment: Read the linked question.

Comment: but they are for the insert, i need for update

Comment: It's done the same way in any type of query.

Comment: i'm trying so, but not work

Comment: prezzo = 386

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = ("UPDATE calendario set costo_volo=%s where id_data=%s", (386, 753))

mycursor.execute(sql)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "Prezzo Aggiornato! (prezzo €)")

Comment: ok i solved it

prezzo = 385

id_data = 753

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "UPDATE calendario SET costo_volo = %s WHERE id_data = %s"
val = (prezzo, id_data)

mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record aggiornato", prezzo, "€")